# namespace "FileToSend" does not exist

Tags: c#, telegram-bot

Hi I want to send a photo with my telegram bot but my VS doesn't recognize "FileToSend" and my error is :

```
int chatId = int.Parse(dgReport.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString());
FileStream imageFile = System.IO.File.Open(txtFilePath.Text,FileMode.Open);

bot.SendPhotoAsync(chatId, new FileToSend("1234.jpg", imageFile), txtmessage.Text);
```

> CS0246    The type or namespace name 'FileToSend' could not be found (are
>   you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Do you not have a reference to the namespace that FileToSend belongs to?

Comment: FileToSend is belong to Telegram.Bot.Types but i have using this however filetosend is not recogniz

Comment: Update your post.  Write up a short [MCVE] that illustrates the compile error, and include the complete code from your MCVE (*ESPECIALLY* your "using" statements!).  Your "using" should typically include `Telegram.Bot;`, 
`Telegram.Bot.Types;` and `Telegram.Bot.Types.Enums;`.

Comment: i have also using Telegram.bot; , Telegram.Bot.Types; , Telegram.Bot.Types.Enums; but its not working yet @paulsm4

Comment: Note the question - "are you missing a using directive OR an assembly reference?" Do you have _both_ the assembly reference AND the correct `using`?

Comment: Dude - what you're *NOT* telling us is key to solving the problem :(  That's why getting in the habit of writing a quick/dirty [MCVE] is so valuable.  For *any* developer, for *many* commonplace problems (like this).  It helps you "isolate the variables".   In this case, you need to a) check your "using" directives.  If that doesn't pan out, then b) Check your "assembly" directives.

Comment: sorry im new in VS how can i Check assembly directives??

Answer (score 4):

The `FileToSend()` function is removed, use `InputOnlineFile()`:

```
FileStream imageFile = System.IO.File.Open(txtFilePath.Text,FileMode.Open);
bot.SendPhotoAsync(chatId, new InputOnlineFile(imageFile, "image.png"), txtmessage.Text);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are very new to Visual Studio and also C# so I'll share a general tip. If you see a red squiggly line in Visual Studio you have a compile error. Your program will not build/run until it is fixed.

Here's my tip. Find the code that is causing the compile error (the text with a red squiggle beneath it). Right click the text and choose "Quick Actions and Refactoring". You will see several suggestions that may fix the issue.

The problem you are describing can *usually* be fixed using this feature. One of the options may be something like "Using Telegram.Bot;". If you choose it, it will automatically put the using statement at the top of your file and fix the compilation error. This is definitely the #1 reason I use Quick Actions and Refactoring.

[image]

Comment: actually i see this first and i try all of suggestion but nothing were my answer

Comment: How have you added the telegram bot package to your project? I ask because there are a couple ways you can do it.

Comment: i just download it from NuGet

Comment: OK awesome. Well if you are doing everything right, your nuget cache might be messed up. Try uninstalling and reinstalling the package into your project.

Comment: In that case, update your question with all the code for the whole .cs file where you are seeing the compile error.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the question is quite OK. I think you just might be mixing up examples you've found and tried, which - if so - is an honest mistake. The `FileToSend()` function is related to a (deprecated) project on GitHub at [ScottRFrost/TelegramBot](https://github.com/ScottRFrost/TelegramBot/).

The rest of your sample seems to be mixed up a bith with, I assume, the [TelegramBots/Telegram.Bot](https://github.com/TelegramBots/telegram.bot) package. If you use that, the following sample might help you a bit further:

```cs
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Telegram.Bot;
using Xunit;

namespace StackOverflowSupport
{
    public class Tests
    {
        [Fact]
        public async Task SendFileWithTelegramBot()
        {
            // Requires NuGet package `Telegram.Bot` (v15.0.0)
            var token = "YOUR_TOKEN";

            using (var http = new HttpClient())
            {
                int chatId = 42;
                var imageFile = File.Open("filepath", FileMode.Open);

                var bot = new TelegramBotClient(token, http);
                await bot.SendPhotoAsync(chatId, photo: imageFile, caption: "This is a Caption");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, no `FileToSend()` in there, which might be the cause of your problem.

Note that this is just to help you in the right direction; it is not meant as code to be used in production. Especially reading out the stream through `File.Open` could be improved.